# Feature image not upload from front-end post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin where user is able to submit a post with a feature image. However, the feature image set to post but does not upload to directory.

**HTML Input Field**

```
<form id="fep-new-post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input placeholder="Add Post Title" type="text" id ="fep-post-title" name="post-title"/>
            <p>
            <?php 
            $settings = array(
            'textarea_rows' => 12,
            'teeny' => false,
            'quicktags' => false,
            'textarea_name' => 'post-content',
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'editor_class' => 'front-end-post',
            'tinymce' => array(
                'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,' .
                    'bullist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter' .
                    ',justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|' .
                    ',spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv'
                )
            );
            wp_editor( '', 'content', $settings);
            ?>
            </p>
            <p>

                <select id="user_submitted_categories"  name="post-category"> 
                 <option value="<?php null ?>">Select category</option> 
                 <?php 
                  $categories = get_categories(); 
                  foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $option = '<option value="'.$category->cat_ID.'">';
                    $option .= $category->cat_name;
                    $option .= '</option>';
                    echo $option;
                  }
                 ?>
            </select>
            </p>
    <input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload"  multiple="false" />
            <p><input id="fep-tags" name="tags" type="text" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add Post tag"/></p>
            <input class="button" onclick="requiredInput()" id="submit" type="submit" tabindex="3" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Publish', 'exclutips-fep' ); ?>" />                    
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
            <input type="hidden" name="empty-description" id="empty-description" value="1"/>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
                    'post_author'   => $user_id,
                    'post_title'    => $post_title,
                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                    'post_content'  => $post_content,
                    'post_category' => $post_category,
                    'tags_input'    => $tags,
                    'post_status'   => 'publish'
                    ) );    

   $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
            $post_image     = $_POST['my_image_upload'];

            $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $post_image);

            move_uploaded_file( $post_image, $uploadfile );
            $filename = basename( $uploadfile );

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

            $attachment = array(
                'guid'           => $uploaddir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile, $post_id );

            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Comment: you need to show us what your HTML form looks like. No idea what `$_POST['my_image_upload']` is supposed to represent, a file or a filename? if  a file, it needs to be `$_FILES['my_image_upload']`

Comment: @Fred-ii-  My question Updated

Comment: I also made an edit to my comment which is what it needs to be `$_FILES` and not `$_POST` and posted my answer below about it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had to re-edit to place a line above your code that belonged with my error reporting ;-) all is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're dealing with a file here and not an (text) input.

Therefore, you need to change `$_POST['my_image_upload']` to `$_FILES['my_image_upload']`

as per your file form element:

```
<input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload"  multiple="false" />
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Plus, make sure the folder you are uploading to, has the right permissions to write to it.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Edit:** Added by the OP in an edit, where I made a slight edit for the line above ^

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_author'   => $user_id,
            'post_title'    => $post_title,
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_content'  => $post_content,
            'post_category' => $post_category,
            'tags_input'    => $tags,
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
            ) );            

        //=============================================================
        $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
        $file = $_FILES['my_image_upload'];
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );

        move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile );
        $filename = basename( $uploadfile );

        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Comment: DId it now but no luck :( may be I have error in my php section `Warning: Illegal offset type in` this error shows when I change the `$post_image = $_FILES[array('my_image_upload')];` coz `$_FILES` required array

Comment: @Firefog Ok, I think I might know why. Change `name="my_image_upload"` in your input to `name="my_image_upload[]"` I had a feeling about that earlier. It needs to be treated as an array.

Comment: @Firefog you said you used `$post_image = $_FILES[array('my_image_upload')];`? didn't you not do `$post_image     = $_FILES['my_image_upload'];`? you posted `$post_image     = $_POST['my_image_upload'];`

Comment: Yes I try this also but `$post_image = $_FILES['my_image_upload'];` shows error `Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in`

Comment: @Firefog have a look at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/upload-gives-no-response-errors-in-server-logs someone mentioned about installing the GD package. This might be the same case for you. However, I found in http://support.proboards.com/thread/330395/php-upload-form-working *Exactly what the error says. `echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']). " has been uploaded";`  `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` is an Array. `basename` only accepts strings. `echo "The file ", htmlentities($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]), " has been uploaded";`* so try that, using `htmlentities`

Comment: @Firefog Plus, since you're using `action=""` you also need to use a conditional statement around it, such as a `if(!empty(...))` or `if(isset(...))` for the file variable/$_FILES declaration.

Comment: also try removing the basename `$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . ($post_image);` or `$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . $post_image;` with no brackets @Firefog and refreshing your browser. Might be a cache issue also.

Comment: @Firefog there is another thing though. Have a look through the manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php about `move_uploaded_file` where it states `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {` using `['tmp_name']` under **Example #2 Validating file uploads**. That might be an additional factor here. Uploaded files bases itself on a temp file then using that to be transferred as the file name itself. This could be a mixture of many different things. I did what I could to help you out and hope you can sort all of this out.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see your form so I only can make a guess.

Maybe you are missing the **enctype** attribute (enctype="multipart/form-data") on your form. This is required if you want upload images.

If do you have the **enctype** attribute in your form, please ignore this answer but post also your HTML here so we can see what is going on!

Comment: Plus, the method used must be post. edit: never mind I just noticed, they do have it in `'post_type'     => 'post',` but what you said is correct. However, some part of their post is unclear.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- Good night, fine to see you here again!

Comment: Cheers Franco ;-) ditto